# Can a attribute be controlled inside a button for certain conditions with the use of flag in controller using angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outlined" ng-click="vm.change()" data-modal-target="#add-save-all-alert-modal"></button>
```

I have an attribute called "data-modal-target" in my HTML which helps me to invoke a modal if ng-click.....I want to control the attribute inside my controller for certain conditions(by setting flags may be)...how can I do that?

```
vm.change = function () {
if(vm.modifiedBaseline &&  vm.modifiedBaselineToBeCommented){
 vm.modalFlag = true;
} 
else{
     st1;
     st2;
}
vm.modalFlag = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inside your `ng-click()` event you can write this code

```
$scope.change= function ($index) {
        $('#add-save-all-alert-modal').modal('show');

    };
```

Please let me know if this helped

Comment: Thanks:)...but that won't work for the carbon theme classes in modal HTML...else it works fine for bootstrap classes.....@Rohan